# Play Audio with jquery without loop

Tags: jquery, html, audio

I plan to play audio with jquery in a page with `mouseenter` event.
So the problem is every time mouse enter over the button audio will play. So i searched alot in `api.jquery.com` for play() But can't found anything .

Please help

```
<audio id="notifi" src="http://example.com/intuition.mp3"></audio>
```

```
$(smart_assistant).mouseenter(function(){
    $("#notifi").get(0).play();
  });
```

Comment: What is `smart_assistant` a reference to?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan This is the Button `id` that `mouseenter` event will affect on it

Comment: If that's the case then the code you have should already work: https://jsfiddle.net/1tgop7Lm/. Check the console for errors and verify `smart_assistant` is valid

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Probably you don't get my point . My code is working and audio will play correctly , I Don't want to audio play every time mouse will enter over the button.

Comment: It doesn't, it only plays once as you can see from the fiddle. If you want to stop it then just call `stop()` or `pause()` under the relevant event, exactly as you do now with `play()`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes, But after song fully played, If you move cursor over the button, It will played again So i don't want it . I want if Song played once , Never get played again.

Comment: That would have been good to have known in the question :) `$(smart_assistant).one('mouseenter', function() {...`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks, In question title i think it explained clearly . But thanks it works .

Comment: Looping means playing the same file immediately after it ends, not triggering an event only once, but glad you solved the problem